# How does the compiler determine between a function using SFINAE and a standard function if both are viable?

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    // Allow func to be called if T is the const version of T2
    // e.g., T is 'int const' and T2 is 'int'
    template <typename T2,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<
                                          std::is_same<T, T2 const>::value>::type>
    void func(A<T2> const &)
    {
        std::cout << "Conversion" << std::endl;
    }

    // Allow func to be called for same version of T
    void func(A const &)
    {
        std::cout << "No conversion" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<int const> a;

    a.func(A<int const>{});

    return 0;
}
```

This code, when compiled with GCC-8.3 compiles and produces the output `No conversion` - it selected the version of `func` that does not use `std::enable_if`. However, if I comment out the second version of `func`, it will still compile and now produce the output `Conversion`. In other words, both versions of `func` within `A` are usable for this method. Given that both overloads are viable, what specific rule is the compiler using to select `func(A const &)` over the other version (`func(A<T2> const &)`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is that if a non function template and a function template specialization have the same signature, then the non function template is chosen over the template specialization.  This can be found in [[over.match.best]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.best#2)

> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>
> [...]
>
> - F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function template specialization [...]

Answer (score 4):

You can read about overload resolution [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). In particular

> If any candidate is a function template, its specializations are generated using template argument deduction, and such specializations are treated just like non-template functions except where specified otherwise in the tie-breaker rules.

And then

> **Best viable function**
>
> For each pair of viable function F1 and F2, the implicit conversion sequences from the i-th argument to i-th parameter are ranked to determine which one is better [...]
>
> F1 is determined to be a better function than F2 if implicit conversions for all arguments of F1 are not worse than the implicit conversions for all arguments of F2, and 
>   [...]
>
> 4) [...] F1 is a non-template function while F2 is a template specialization

Basically the same rules apply in this simpler example:

```
#include<iostream>

template <typename T> 
void foo(T i) { std::cout << "template" ; }

void foo(int i) { std::cout << "non template"; }

int main() {
    foo(1);   // non template
}
```