# How does the compiler differentiate between the constructors of std::vector?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, constructor

The `std::vector<T>` class has the following two constructors:

```cpp
vector(size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
template <class InputIt>
vector(InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

When instantiated with `T=size_t`, these seem to be able to clash (with `InputIt=size_t`), but it does not happen. Why?

For clarity, here's a minimal code sample:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct A {
  A(size_t n, const T &v) { std::cout << n << " x " << v << std::endl; }
  template <typename I>
  A(I first, I last) { std::cout << first << " ... " << last << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  size_t x = 3, y = 42;
  A<size_t> a1(x, y);    // prints 3 x 42
  A<size_t> a2(3, 42);   // prints 3 ... 42
}
```

EDIT: I put @jrok's version also in the example. Why is one of the constructors prioritized in `a1`, and the other one in `a2`?

Comment: Templates are resolved based on type of passed parameters. first is of type iterator and count is having type size_t these are resolved at compile time only.

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector: *"This overload only participates in overload resolution if InputIt satisfies LegacyInputIterator, to avoid ambiguity with the overload (3)."*. So SFINAE should probably happen somewhere.

Comment: CppCon 2018: Walter E. Brown “C++ Function Templates: How Do They Really Work?” : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIDEjY5ywqU

Comment: This was referred to during standardization as the "do the right thing" requirement: the details of how it would be done were left to the implementation. Standard library implementations don't have to be written in portable C++ code, so can use any compiler-specific tricks to get the right answer. Now that we have more powerful template programming idioms it's easy: SFINAE to the rescue! Note that "only participates in overload resolution..." isn't the original wording; that phraseology was introduced into the standard later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is required, during overload resolution, to drop the template overload from the set of candidate functions when `InputIt` is not deduced as an iterator type (more formally, when it doesn't satisfy `LegacyInputIterator` concept - see note (5) on [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)).

Removing overloads in user code is done with [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) technique, altough the compiler implementaion could use something else - they're not strictly required to use legal C++ code. For example, my (MinGW) compiler implements it with SFINAE:

```
template<typename _InputIterator,
           typename = std::_RequireInputIter<_InputIterator>>
    vector(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
       const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type());
```

where `_RequireInputIter` is

```
 template<typename _InIter>
    using _RequireInputIter = typename
      enable_if<is_convertible<typename
        iterator_traits<_InIter>::iterator_category,
                   input_iterator_tag>::value>::type;
```

This requirement came into effect with C++11, so prior to it, you could in fact call the wrong constructor. If we modify your example a little:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct A {
  A(size_t n, const T &v) { std::cout << n << " x " << v << std::endl; }
  template <typename I>
  A(I first, I last) { std::cout << first << " ... " << last << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  A<size_t> a(3, 42);
}
```

it now prints `3 ... 42`.

Comment: Thanks, this largely answers my question. But shouldn't the compiler throw an error when there are two valid resolutions (like in your modified example)?

Comment: @vukung There are two valid overloads, but one is better than the other. What exactly makes one better (both in your and my example) - that I'm not sure yet :)

Answer (score 3):

In [[sequence.reqmts]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements#sequence.reqmts-3) the standard has

> [...] `i` and `j` denote iterators that meet the Cpp17InputIterator requirements and refer to elements implicitly convertible to `value_­type` [...]

And this requirement means that

```
template <class InputIt>
vector(InputIt first, InputIt last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Is only viable if `InputIt` is actually a input iterator or better.  This means that the implementation must use SFINAE or other techniques to make this overload not considered when `InputIt` is not an actual iterator type.  `size_t` is not an iterator type so the only constructor that can be used to construct the object is

```
vector(size_type count, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

---

This is different from your minimal example.  With your minimal example you could call

```
A(size_t n, const size_t &v) - non-template-specialization
// or
A(size_t first, size_t last) - template-specialization
```

And if by the rules of [[over.ics.ref]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.best#over.ics.ref-1) both functions are equally good since `const size_t &` is considered the identity transformation which means the non-template-specialization is called as [those are preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60328852/how-does-the-compiler-determine-between-a-function-using-sfinae-and-a-standard-f) to template-specializations

Comment: But signature cannot be changed, right? So it is selected but acts as the other one.

Comment: @Jarod42 AFAIK, the implementation is allowed to use SFINAE to make a function behave correctly.  Does adding SFINAE really change the signature?

Comment: What I really can't understand is how the minimal example is working. AFAIK the template should be chosen since it is an exact match while the non-template preforms a const conversion.  I think there is a DR or CWG issue about it, but I can't find it.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Exactly, if this would be the solution, the minimal example wouldn't work.

Comment: @Jarod42: SFINAE means "Substitution Failure Is Not An Error". The idea here is that the Substitution of `InputIt` fails for `size_t`. It's not an error so your program still compiles. But the substitution failed, and therefore no signature exists.

Comment: @vukung I've updated my answer to explain the behavior of your minimal example.

Comment: @MSalters: my concern was most from a Lawyer point of view. SFINAE via template parameter seems viable (whereas by default parameter (or return value for non constructor) would change signature, which IMO, is not allowed). From the wording *"This constructor has the same effect as"* (until C++11), it seems there is tag dispatching from inside the function, whereas *"This overload only participates"* requires SFINAE.

Comment: @Jarod42: Changing the signature is allowed. You can't take the address of a constructor anyway.